# How to display data from datagrid to radio button?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm new to WPF, and I want when I click on the DataGrid the RadioButton will display the same data as in the DataGrid.

sorry for my bad English.

Code #

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  DataGrid datagrid = (DataGrid)sender;
  DataRowView row_selected = datagrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

  if (row_selected != null)
  {
    Name_txt.Text = row_selected["Name"].ToString();
    Age_txt.Text = row_selected["Age"].ToString();
    Address_txt.Text = row_selected["Address"].ToString();
    if (rbMale.IsChecked == true)
    {
      row_selected["Gender"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
      row_selected["Gender"].ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

I hope to get some simple answers as I am new to WPF.

Comment: `If(row_selected["Gender"].ToString() =="Male") {rbMale.IsChecked = true;}` this is what you are trying to do?

Comment: i tried your way but it doesn't work, when i click on the datagrid, the radiobutton still doesn't change when i select Male or Female

Comment: A common pattern is to bind datacontext of a panel such as a stackpanel to selecteditem of a datagrid. Anything in that panel can then bind to properties of whichever item the user chooses in the datagrid.

Comment: I recommend you learn mvvm if you're going to do any substantial wof development. Are you just using ado? I recommend using an orm. I like Dapper.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple code:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="RadioButtonDataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadioButtonDataGridTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Loaded="OnLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

            <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Name" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Name_txt" />

            <Label FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,10,0,0">Male or female?</Label>
            <RadioButton GroupName="sex" Name="rbMale">Male</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton GroupName="sex" Name="rbFemale">Female</RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

As you wish, the `RadioButton` is selected when the `DataGrid` selection change

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> people;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get { return people; } }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        people.Clear();
        people.Add(new Person() { Name="John", Age=12, Address="John address", Gender="Male"});
        people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Mary", Age = 23, Address = "Mary address", Gender = "Female" });
    }

    private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = null;
        DataGrid datagrid = (DataGrid)sender;

        if (datagrid == null || datagrid.SelectedItems.Count != 1) return;
        
        person = datagrid.SelectedItem as Person;
        
        if (person != null)
        {
            Name_txt.Text = person.Name;
            //Age_txt.Text = row_selected["Age"].ToString();
            //Address_txt.Text = row_selected["Address"].ToString();
            if (person.Gender == "Male") rbMale.IsChecked = true;
            else if (person.Gender == "Female") rbFemale.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

May I suggest you to use Enum or integer (byte) value to manage the gender than compare strings?

**The model**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```